# How can I get ^C to show up when I do Control-C on a Mac terminal?

Tags: terminal

If I type a command, and halfway through I decide not to run that command, I do a Control-C to cancel it without having to backspace the whole thing, e.g. `mv foo.txt bar.txt`. On Ubuntu it'll show up as `mv foo.txt bar.txt^C` to remind me I cancelled it, but on Mac it shows up as just `mv foo.txt bar.txt`. Any way to get that `^C` behaviour on Mac?

Comment: It shows `^C` for me in Terminal under OS X 10.8.5.  What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: I'm on 10.10.5. It shows up when a cancel a process halfway through, but not when I press Control-C before even hitting Enter

Comment: @user3439894 I'm running 10.11.1 and it doesn't show `^C` for me, either.

Comment: @user3439894 Maybe it only shows `^C` in older versions?

Comment: Try updating bash with homebrew if that's what you use

Comment: This was reported as a bug:  http://superuser.com/questions/189127/mac-os-terminal-keyboard-echo-breaks-after-ctrl-c-with-some-applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of this, but for a different reason I upgrade the Bash on my machine (`brew install bash`) and this behaviour started to show up. This [post](https://johndjameson.com/blog/updating-your-shell-with-homebrew/) is what I followed to update Bash. It would be good practice not to overwrite your old Bash but instead just use the new one. Brew puts the new Bash at `/local/usr/bin/bash` anyway.

Answer (score -1):

On most Unix systems you can modify the shell to either show the output of the control character as the character or as a "^C".  This can be done with the `echoctl` or `ctlecho` stty modes.

Use `stty echoctl` to print the ^C characters

and `stty -echoctl` to allow the shell to print the control character as the actual character, a `SIGINT` in this case.

Doing this on a Linux machine seems to alter the behavior correctly, but on my MAC it will not show the character either way, on 10.11.something.

Comment: From your last sentence this is not an answer